# Is it possible to configure a custom default scriptlet for every report on Jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to configure by default a custom scriptlet to every report I have without the need of setting it by hand in every report.

Is it possible? (By default, Jasper uses its own `JRDefaultScriptlet` class)

Thank you!

Comment: 1) You can customize JasperReports source code (*DefaultScriptletFactory* class); 2) You can create wrapper for setting  *JRParameter.REPORT_SCRIPTLET* parameter

Comment: I cannot use the (2) option, but the first seems promising. I didn't found an example about factories, could you add one? @AlexK?